# Proof of a technical fact in the book of Schapire and Freund on boosting

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, inequality

I am currently looking at Exercise 10.3, Chapter 10 of the [book on Boosting](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj79Kba39jeAhVGNOwKHZXPBNkQFjABegQIDRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.lagout.org%2Fscience%2F0_Computer%2520Science%2F2_Algorithms%2FBoosting_%2520Foundations%2520and%2520Algorithms%2520%255BSchapire%2520%2526%2520Freund%25202012-05-18%255D.pdf&usg=AOvVaw25HbLNltegBUZJFQck9ifH) by Schapire and Freund. More precisely, in the middle of the exercise they propose to use, without proof, the technical fact summarized below. Obviously, since it can be used without proof, I am now curious to know how to prove it!

---

To summarize the problem, let $\mathcal{H}$ bet a set of functions $h : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{\bar{Y}} \rightarrow [-1,1]$. Define $\text{co}(\mathcal{H})$ as 
\begin{align*}
\text{co}(\mathcal{H}) = \left\lbrace f : x,\bar{y} \mapsto \sum_{t=1}^T a_t h_t(x,\bar{y}) \left| a_1,\ldots,a_T \geq 0; \sum_{t=1}^Ta_t = 1; h_1,\ldots h_T \in \mathcal{H}; T\geq 1 \right.  \right\rbrace\text{.}
\end{align*}
Notice that $f : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{\bar{Y}} \rightarrow [-1,1]$. For $f \in \text{co}\left(\mathcal{H}\right)$, $\eta > 0$, $\bar{K} = |\mathcal{\bar{Y}}|$, and $(x,y) \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$, let
\begin{align*}
\nu_{f,\eta}(x,y) = - \frac{1}{\eta} \ln\left(\frac{1}{\bar{K}} \sum_{\bar{y} \in \mathcal{\bar{Y}}} \exp\Big(-\eta \Omega(y,\bar{y}) f(x,\bar{y})\Big)\right)
\end{align*}
where $\Omega(y,\bar{y}) = 1$ if $\bar{y} \in \Omega(y)$ and $-1$ otherwise. $\Omega(y)$ associates each element from $\mathcal{Y}$ to a subset of $\mathcal{\bar{Y}}$. Notice that $\nu_{f,\eta} : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \rightarrow [-1,1]$.

The technical fact is as follows. Let $1 \geq \theta > 0$ and define the grid:
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_\theta = \left\lbrace \frac{4\ln\bar{K}}{i\theta} : i = 1, \ldots, \left\lceil \frac{8\ln\bar{K}}{\theta^2} \right\rceil \right\rbrace\text{.}
\end{align*}
For any $\eta > 0$, let $\hat{\eta}$ be the closest value in $\varepsilon_\theta$ to $\eta$. Then for all $f \in \text{co}(\mathcal{H})$ and for all $(x,y) \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$,
\begin{align*}
\left| \nu_{f,\eta}(x,y) - \nu_{f,\hat{\eta}}(x,y) \right| \leq \frac{\theta}{4}\text{.}
\end{align*}

---

So far, I proved the statement when $\eta > \frac{4\ln\bar{K}}{\theta}$ (using the properties of the LogSumExp function). Furthermore, using the grid, I showed that
\begin{align*}
&& \left| \eta - \hat{\eta} \right| \leq \frac{\ln \bar{K}}{\theta} \\
&\Rightarrow& \left| \eta\nu_{f,\eta}(x,y) - \hat{\eta}\nu_{f,\hat{\eta}}(x,y) \right| \leq \frac{\ln \bar{K}}{\theta}\text{.}
\end{align*}
However, I did not manage to go further than that.

---

Am I going in the right direction? If yes, what would be the trick for the last step? If no, what method should I consider to prove this statement? Note that I am not asking for a full proof, but rather some hints on how to proceed to show the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\Omega(y,\bar{y}) = 1$ if $\bar{y} \in \Omega(y)$"? $\bar y\in \mathcal{\bar Y}$ and $\Omega(x)\in\mathcal{\bar Y}$. How can $\bar{y} \in \Omega(y)$?

Comment: $\Omega(y)$ is a function that associates each element in $\mathcal{Y}$ to one or several elements in $\bar{\mathcal{Y}}$. In other words $\Omega(y) \subseteq \bar{\mathcal{Y}}$. I modified the question to clarify this point.